# without displaying the alert message,how to get the user current locatation latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My client ask no need to display alert message while displaying user current locatation and also how to get user latitude and longitude on mapview.

anybody help me pls without displaying the alert message on mapview, how can we get the lat & long.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    //display current location
    [self.mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];

     //get the current location latitude and algitude
    NSString *lati = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *lang = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"lati  : %@",lati);
    NSLog(@"langi  : %@",lang);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't. This is a privacy consideration build into iOS. The alert is presented automatically when you first request access to the location data. You should not want to subvert this privacy management.